# Read characteristics on ble not called

Tags: android, android-ble

I am very much new to ble and still trying my hand in it. In my app, I am trying to send a byte array to the ble device and in response, will be recieving a byte array from the device. However onCharacteristicRead() is not called. I know something is missing from my code side but I am unable to figure it out. Please do help. Thank you in advance. Below I am posting my code:

```
     @Override
                        public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status) {


                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "Service uuid ");

                                    List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = gatt.getServices();

                                    Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "Services count: "+gattServices.size());

                                    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

                                        ArrayList<String> alst_uuid = new ArrayList<String>();
                                        // List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = gatt.getServices();
                                        // Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "Services count: "+gattServices.size());

                                        for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
                                            String serviceUUID = gattService.getUuid().toString();
                                            if(serviceUUID.equalsIgnoreCase("56788877-e7cb-469b-6578-2742f1ba77cc"))
                                            {
                                                for(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic: gattService.getCharacteristics())
                                                {
                                                    if(characteristic.getUuid().toString().equals("xxxxxxx-b042-4876-aae1-112855353cc1"))
                                                    {
                                                        Log.d("foundoutchar", characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                                                        String originalString = "BB0100017E";
                                                        byte[] byt_arr = hexStringToByteArray(originalString);
                                                        characteristic.setValue(byt_arr); // call this BEFORE(!) you 'write' any stuff to the server
                                                        gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            alst_uuid.add(serviceUUID);
                                            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> list = gattService.getCharacteristics();
                                            Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "Service uuid "+serviceUUID);
                                            serviceObject object = new serviceObject();
                                            String characteristics ="";
                                            String properties ="";
                                            for(int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++)
                                            {

                                                Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "Service Characteristics "+list.get(i).getUuid());
                                                characteristics = characteristics+""+list.get(i).getUuid()+"\\\n";
                                                properties = properties+""+list.get(i).getProperties()+"\\\n";


                                                Log.d("onServicesDiscovered", "Service Properties "+list.get(i).getProperties());


                                            }




                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("log", "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }

                                @Override
                                public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                                    super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
                                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            Log.d("onCharacteristicWrite","writing"+characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
                                    super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
                                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            Log.d("onCharacteristic","writing"+characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            };
                    BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt =  result.getDevice().connectGatt(MainActivity.this, true, gattCallback);

                }
               }

            // auto scroll for text view
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

onCharacteristicRead is called in response to a readCharacteristic command, which it doesn't look like your code is issuing.

If your peripheral is set to reply with a byte automatically to your written byte, then it like you're after notifications or indications. These can be captured using [onCharacteristicChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onCharacteristicChanged) But you have to enable notification for each characteristic during set up.

If your device isn't designed to reply using notifications then you should issue a readCharacteristic from the onCharacteristicWrite callback.

Comment: BDW, I am getting status as 0 in onCharacteristicsWrite()

Comment: Thank you, Let me check.